# Complexity of $FP^{NP}$

Tags: complexity-theory

what is the complexity of $FP^{NP}$ w.r.t. $FPSPACE$?

Also can someone please provide a few examples of Problems complete for $FP^{NP}$? If possible let the examples be natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think it's correct to write "w.r.t. $\mathsf{PSPACE}$" since $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ is a set of decision problems, while $\mathsf{FP^{NP}}$ is a set of functional problems which is contained in $\mathsf{FPSPACE}$. These (which you are interested in) problems can be solved by polynomial amount of queries to $\mathsf{NP}$ oracle (that returns YES/NO answer).
2. A simple example of such problem is:

Given a DNF find an equivalent DNF which has as it's terms only prime (those which cannot be shortened) implicants. It can be solved with linear amount of queries to TAUT/SAT oracle.

Comment: Thank you. will update. I just read TSP is complete for $FP^{NP}$ where as Clique is complete for $FP^{NP[log]}$. When we say TSP or Clique I assume it is finding the size of the TSP and Clique respectively or is it finding the actual TSP or Clique ?

Comment: Well, I think, they are asking for a path/clique itself, not the size/distance, because you can't find a solution knowing only size/distance, but can evaluate size/distance from solution.

Comment: But, I am unable to see how $log$ amount of queries to an $NP$ Oracle can find the clique? The Oracle only gives a boolean answer, and in $#log$ number of $NP$ queries, at best we can decide for only that many nodes in the Graph. Or I missed something ?

Comment: Well, that is already another question. But I'll give you a hint: you can use binary search via oracle.

Comment: I think, Its the value and not the actual clique.  Please check out and confirm. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900396

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand: it's really true since such searching only allows you to find a value. Finding an object itself is a problem from $\mathsf{FP^{FNP}}$. I can be incorrect since I don't understand those functional classes well.

Answer (score 2):

Both $\mathrm{FP}$ and $\mathrm{NP}$ are included in polynomial space so $\mathrm{FP^{NP}}$ is, too,  since you can simulate the computation and its oracle.  Note that, strictly speaking, you need to  compare against $\mathrm{FPSPACE}$, since $\mathrm{FP}$ is a set of function problems, whereas $\mathrm{PSPACE}$ is a set of decision problems.

Comment: A follow up Query: The TSP's functional version is complete for $FP^{SAT}[n^{O(1)}]$. And as I understand the $[..]$ represents the number of Queries we are allowed to make to an $NP$ Oracle to solve the problem in polynomial time (by definition of $FP^{SAT}$). But, I am unsure in case of TSP, what the variable $n$ represents?

Comment: @J.Doe That seems strange, as an $\mathrm{FP}$ machine can't possibly make more than polynomially many oracle calls, so it would be weird to state the restriction. But new questions shuold be asked as new questions -- link back to this one if you think the context is needed.

Comment: I am not sure what $n$ is. here is the paper. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900396. will do.

Comment: @J.Doe You need to ask your new question as a new question. Comments are for pointing out problems with answers and requesting clarifications, not for discussion.